# published chrome extension in web store and its not available in web store

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, google-chrome-devtools

Recently I published a chrome extension in web store and its not available in web store.

**Add to chrome** option is not enabled when I share the web store link of the extension with others.

Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1.Open Dashboard 
2.Edit your tool
3.Visibility options -> public
```